How to not turn off display after Lock Ubuntu 24.04
I use Window (super) + L to lock screen then It locked and It turn to black screen immediately. I just want it to appear lock screen or screen saver. How to fix this?
I see the same issue here but not have solution yet: Lock but do not turn off display
